# How to read the values from the dynamically added script tag in head using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script tag which is getting from the service. I am just appending it to the head part of the html.

Its getting appended but the thing is it has some values which I need to access in my application.

```
<script>

abc.header.value = "1";
abc.header.path = "/abc/def/ghi?isThirdParty=false&version=v123";

</script>
```

Once the script is added to header if I try to access abc.header.value it's throwing undefined.

How to access values from the added script. and also i have a global object, is there a way to added all this dynamically added values to that object?

sample Snippet:
 I am getting script tag from the ajax call and am storing it in a variable.

```
var sampSnip = "<script> abc.header.value = "1"; abc.header.path = "/abc/def/ghi?isThirdParty=false&version=v123"; </script>";

$('head').append(sampSnip);
```

Comment: can you show where u r trying to access `abc.header.value`?

Comment: A few debugging steps -  `console.log(abc)` then `console.log(abc.header)`. See if your variable value exists in these objects. 2. If they show the object but your `value` and `path` are missing, then you are trying access them before it is assigned.

Comment: It depends on how you inserted those "new" variables, post your code which creates the scrip tag and values, and yes definitely a way to dynamically add values to the object, but before that, is this "dynamic" data being generated by the server via an AJAX call?

Comment: @JordanDavis : Yes script tag is getting loaded from the ajax call. I have added a sample snippet

Comment: @M-S thanks for clarifying, so best practice would be to JSON.parse(e.target.response) aka the response from the server, rather than creating a script tag and inserting the values, if you want those to be global you can just set it to a variable and don't use the var keyword. Example - myData = JSON(e.target.response); then console.log(myData).

Comment: @M-S if your using PHP in the backend? Then use the - echo json_encode($data). This will format the data so that you can JSON.parse(response) on the client side.

Comment: @M-S I just took a look at your edit, yea so basically you can't declare a script tag the way your doing it because it won't initialize it, you need to create it via the DOM so that it registers and initialized so like this document.createElement('script') then append it to the head tag, but like I mentioned above just get used to JSON.parse it's a way better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this simple signin form I just wrote for you.

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css"> 
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input id='signin' type="button" value="Sign In">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init(){
    document.getElementById('signin').addEventListener('click', click.signin);
}
var click = {
    "signin": function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputs = e.target.parentNode.children;
        var data = new FormData();
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
            if(inputs[i].type !== 'button'){
                data.append('credentials['+inputs[i].name+']', inputs[i].value);                
            }
        }
        client.addEventListener("load", callback.signin);
        client.open("POST", "/core/signin.php");
        client.send(data);
    }   
};
var callback = {
    "signin": function(e){
        var data = JSON.parse(e.target.response);
        console.log(data);
    }   
};
```

//PHP

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST['credentials']);
?>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #0B9AD8;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
}
form{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 !important;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    -webkit-border-radius: .3em;
    border-radius: .3em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
input{
    width:22em; 
    height: 3em;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: lighter !important; /* FIREFOX */
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff; 
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0 !important; /* FIREFOX */
}
input:-webkit-autofill{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
input[type="button"]{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #0089C4;
    color: #fff;
    background: #0089C4;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
input[type="button"]:hover{
    background: #0B9AD8;
}
input[type="button"]:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
}
```